# laravel 4 head loading in body

Tags: html, laravel

For some reason my scripts,... and everything I declare in the head isn't loaded in the head tag, but inside the body tag. Did I do something wrong? Should I post my controllers/routes files too?

my code:
layouts->master.blade.php

```
<?php
$version = [
    'jQuery-legacy' => '1.11.0', // Previous generation of jQuery
    'jQuery'        => '2.1.0',
    'jQueryMobile'  => '1.4.2',
    'lodash'        => '2.4.1',
    'modernizr'     => '2.7.1',
];
?><!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ HTML::entities('Partycipate') }}</title>
    {{ HTML::style('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'); }}
    {{ HTML::script("//code.jquery.com/jquery-{$version['jQuery']}.min.js") }}
    {{ HTML::script("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/{$version['modernizr']}/modernizr.min.js") }}
    {{ HTML::style("//code.jquery.com/mobile/{$version['jQueryMobile']}/jquery.mobile-{$version['jQueryMobile']}.min.css") }}
    {{ HTML::style('components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'); }}
    {{ HTML::style("styles/global.css") }}
    {{ HTML::style('styles/navigation.css'); }}
    @yield('head')
    {{ HTML::script('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
</head>
<body>
@yield('navigation')
@yield('content')
{{ HTML::script("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/{$version['lodash']}/lodash.mobile.min.js") }}
{{ HTML::script('scripts/plug-ins/sidebar.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('scripts/plug-ins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js') }}
@yield('bottom_scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

and then a page:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('navigation')
    @include('navigation', ['pageActive' => 'overzicht'])
@stop
@section('styles')
@stop

@section('content')
<div class="content-container">

</div>
@stop

@section('bottom_scripts')
    {{ HTML::script("scripts/plug-ins/calendar/moment-2.5.1.js") }}
    {{ HTML::script("scripts/overzicht.js") }}
@stop
```

The rendered HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" 
<head></head>
<body>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Partycipate</title>
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/styles/global.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/styles/navigation.css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class=„content-container”>
    </div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/scripts/plug-ins/sidebar.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/scripts/plug-ins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/scripts/plug-ins/calendar/moment-2.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8181/partycipate/public/scripts/overzicht.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: You don't push anything to your `head` section according to the "page", but you are pushing items to `bottom_scripts` which are located right before the closing body in your layout.

Comment: Hmmn, but why are all the script I declare in the head html tag (in my master) also located in the body then?

Comment: Can you create a paste containing your rendered html ? Might be easier to help that way.

Comment: I added it to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you have some trailing semi-colons in your HTML::style/script's, which shouldn't be there.

Comment: I removed those, it didn't solved the problem :s I also checked my controllers, but I don't see any mistakes there either.

What I do there is (for my index page):

class UserController extends \BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.index');
    } 
}

Comment: I have found the issue is by using controllers to link/create to the page. When I just use:

Route::get('/overzicht', function()
    {
        return View::make('overzicht');
    });

It works, but when I use:

The route:
    Route::get('overzicht', array(
            'uses' => 'CalendarController@makeCalendar'
    ));
And the code I posted in the comment above, it loads the scripts,... in the body?